# Navigation Experimental: How to pass props to scenes?

Tags: navigation, react-native

I am working on the splash screen of my app where data get initialized.

**The desire result is simply:**

1. Load data on componentWillMount: view shows a `loading indicator`
2. On data loaded: view shows a `check icon`
3. After 1 second: navigate to another scene

In order to change the view from showing the `loading indicator` to the `check icon`, I need to update a `dataReady` prop that is passed to the splash screen scene **but I don't know how to do this without updating the navigation state** (i.e. passing props to scenes via the `route` object of the navigation state).

Here is my attempt (which does not work as expected):

```
class MainRouter extends React.Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    // Load data.
    this.props.initApp();
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    // initAppReady is set to true 1 second after data loaded.
    if (nextProps.initAppReady) {
      this.props.handleNavigation({ type: 'PUSH', route: { key: 'home' } });
    }
  }

  renderScene = props => {
    switch (props.scene.key) {
      case 'scene_splash_screen':
        // dataReady is set to true after data loaded.
        return (<SplashScreen dataReady={this.props.dataReady} />);

      case 'scene_home':
        return (<Home />);

      default:
        return null;
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <NavigationCardStack
        direction={'vertical'}
        navigationState={this.props.mainRoutes}
        renderScene={this.renderScene}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

As a result, the `renderScene` method is not called when `props.dataReady` is changed so the `SplashScreen` scene does not update accordingly.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally tried editing your post instead of my answer...ignore my edit. (It just got rejected, sorry about that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a new `AppLoader` component, which displays the splash screen and does the initial data load.  Also, instead of passing in `initAppReady` as a prop to the router, you should have the `initApp` function return a promise, which resolves when the app is ready, then the `AppLoader` can do the the one second pause, and navigate to the home scene.

Note: I noticed you push the home route onto the stack. I suggest you replace the stack with the home route. If you push on to it, then the user could accidentally navigate back to your splash screen, which is probably not what you want.

Here is an example of what I mean:

**MainRouter.js**

```
class MainRouter extends React.Component {

  renderScene = props => {
    switch (props.scene.key) {
      case 'scene_splash_screen':
        return (<AppLoader initApp={this.props.initApp} handleNavigation={this.props.handleNavigation} />);

      case 'scene_home':
        return (<Home />);

      default:
        return null;
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <NavigationCardStack
        direction={'vertical'}
        navigationState={this.props.mainRoutes}
        renderScene={this.renderScene}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

**AppLoader.js**

```
const AFTER_INIT_DELAY = 1000;
class AppLoader extends React.Component {

  static propTypes = {
    initApp: PropTypes.func,
    handleNavigation: PropTypes.func,
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      dataReady: false,
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.initApp()
      .then(() => {
        this.setState({dataReady: true}, this.afterAppInit);
      })
      .catch(() => {
        // Do something if the app init fails
      })
  }

  afterAppInit = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.props.handleNavigation({ type: 'REPLACE', route: { key: 'home' } });
    }, AFTER_INIT_DELAY);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <SplashSceen dataReady={this.state.dataReady} />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: So by `AppLoader component` do you mean a `container` in the redux world? If so, does this mean for every scene that have multiple view states to display should be wrapped inside a container and then supplied to the renderScene?

Comment: No, the `AppLoader` component is just a component that handles the orchestration of the initial app load.  It simply displays the splash screen and triggers the data load (which can update the store and such), then does the "redirect" to the home screen.

It just encapsulates the logic nicer, and prevents you from having to get tricky in the router and trying to update the rendered scene.

Comment: As a side-affect, extracting this out to to its own component like I suggest allows you to easily add things like App Updating and such in a central place.

Comment: Sorry for the comment spam, but just to clarify: Each scene component should handle its own rendering logic.  Meaning, the router should be ignorant if the scene needs to re-render, it should only be concerned with displaying the scenes and navigating between them.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation! I got the picture now. Also thanks for the note about should using 'REPLACE' instead of 'PUSH' to nav to home :)